# AutoMapper - Map destination object's property that does not exist in source object

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I'm casting class `Process` to `ProcessDTO`. The `ProcessDTO` object have a property named `ProcessSteps` that does not exist in `Process`. I want the `ProcessSteps`-property to be casted to `ProcessStepsDto`. I'm using a global configuration for AutoMapper.

I have tried using

```cs
CreateMap<Process, ProcessDto>()
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.Steps, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<ProcessStepDto>(s)));
```

But this is wrong..

```cs
public class Process
{

}

public class ProcessDto
{
//This property does not exists in source object and get's created on get. I want this to be cast to "ProcessStepDto[]"
    public ProcessStep[] Steps
    {
        get
        {
            ProcessStepRepository repository = new ProcessStepRepository();
            return repository.Select(x => x.ProcessId == this.Id && x.Active).OrderBy(x=>x.Position).ToArray();
        }
    }
}

public class ProcessStep
{
 ...
}

public class ProcessStepDto
{
 ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
After i use AutoMapper to mapp my object `Process` to `ProcessDto` i also want the property of `Steps`to be mapped to `ProcessStepsDto`. Currently it stays as `ProcessStep`.
[image]

Comment: Where is your `ProcessSteps` property? Do you mean `ProcessStep[] Steps`? If so, what do you mean by `be cast to "ProcessStepDto[]"`? You are converting `Process` to `ProcessDto`, which class will have `ProcessStepDto`? Share us code related with your source data and your expected data.

Comment: I dont have a `ProcessSteps` property? I want the `Process` to be cast to `ProcessDto` with a new property named `Steps` wich do not exist in `Process`, only in `ProcessDto`. The `Steps` property that exists in `ProcessDto` i want to automatically be cast to `ProcessStepDto[]` type.

Comment: Share us your current model and data for source and the expected result for `ProcessDto`

Comment: @TaoZhou, I've updated the post with an image. I hope that explains better want i want. Regards D,

Comment: It's unclear what is `ProcessStepDto` and `Steps`.

Comment: Steps is a property of the class ProcessDto. I want this property to be cast to the type "ProcessStepDto".

Comment: Adding some clarification.. When i say "cast" i mean that i want it to be mapped using AutoMapper.

Comment: Try `CreateMap<ProcessStep, ProcessStepDto>()`

Comment: I have tried that. I think the problem is that the property `Steps` does not exist in `Process` and only in `ProcessDto`. I've noticed if i add the property `Steps` to `Process` it's getting mapped in `ProcessDto`. However, it would be great to be able to mapp destination properties that does not exist in source.

Comment: What is the expected data for `Steps` while mapping?

Comment: Try to implement custom `ITypeConverter` with your own logic, refer [How to map from a flat entity to more than one DTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939566/how-to-map-from-a-flat-entity-to-more-than-one-dto/56962727#56962727)

Comment: Thanks ! I will look into that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return `ProcessDto` with `ProcessStepDto[]`, the `ProcessDto` should define the property with type `ProcessStepDto[]` instead of `ProcessStep[]`.

```
    public class ProcessDto
    {
        public ProcessStepDto[] Steps
        {
            get
            {
                ProcessStepRepository repository = new ProcessStepRepository();                     

                return repository.Select(x => x.ProcessId == this.Id && x.Active).Select(s => new ProcessStepDto { PropertyInProcessStepDto = s.PropertyInProcessStep }).OrderBy(x=>x.Position).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```